# Is it possible to pause currently running submission scripts in SLURM?

Tags: slurm

I have a few scripts that I sent to a cluster I have access using sbatch. However, I'd like to pause these running scripts without necessarily cancelling their work since they have been running for some time now.

Is there a way to hold/pause currently running jobs without cancelling the job they have already made?

I found in [the following website](https://rc.fas.harvard.edu/resources/documentation/convenient-slurm-commands/) that one can pause them with:

```
To pause a particular job:

scontrol hold <jobid>
```

however, I'm still a bit unsure how to make it work with job arrays.

Comment: seems something like: `scontrol hold <jobid>` work but I want it to also work for job arrays.

Comment: if they are already running, it doesn't seem that slurm is good at intercepting the job and pausing it...not sure if other people have experienced otherwise...

Comment: `scontrol hold <jobid>_*` maybe

Comment: In the "scontrol hold <jobid> ", the id of the job array is sufficient  to pause all the pending jobs related to this id. But running jobs are not affected by this command .

Comment: From the [docs](https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html) `scontrol hold` "prevent[s] a pending job from being started". So it won't affect running jobs, by design.

Answer (score 10):

I believe

```
scontrol suspend
```

does what you want.
From the documentation:

> **suspend** *job_list*
>
> Suspend a running job. The job_list argument is a comma separated list
>   of job IDs. Use the resume command to resume its execution. User
>   processes must stop on receipt of SIGSTOP signal and resume upon
>   receipt of SIGCONT for this operation to be effective. Not all
>   architectures and configurations support job suspension. If a
>   suspended job is requeued, it will be placed in a held state.

Comment: Any user is not necessarily able to call this admin functionality. According to the documentation, continued:
... Only an operator, administrator, SlurmUser, or root can suspend jobs.